# is it possible to config the npm fallback registry

Tags: registry, pnpm

Now I am using the local registry that behind the nexus:

```
registry = "http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/npm-proxy/"
```

this works fine with the local area network, but when I changed the network. it shows error:

```
ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/npm-proxy/canvas: request to http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/npm-proxy/canvas failed, reason: Socket timeout
```

I was wonder the npm registry support configure the fallback registry? If the local proxy registry could not work, just fallback to the official registry. BTW, I am using pnpm:

```
$ pnpm version                                                                                                                                                     ‹ruby-2.7.2›
{
  npm: '8.5.0',
  node: '16.14.2',
  v8: '9.4.146.24-node.20',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1n+quic',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2021a3',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

I have added the `pnpmfile.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    hooks: {
        readPackage(pkg) {
            if (pkg.registry === 'http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/npm-proxy') {
                pkg.registry = 'https://registry.npm.taobao.org';
            }
            return pkg;
        },
    },
};
```

but did not work.